# Map two elements in different arrays (or models) with their id in swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have these 2 JSON. and what I want to do is to get the first NAME that corresponds to that ID.

```json
{
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 10765,
            "name": "Action & Adventure"
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Animation"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "genre_ids": [
                10765,
                18,
                10759
            ]
            "vote_count": 1365
        },
        {
            "genre_ids": [
                10474,
                18,
                10759,
            ],
            "vote_count": 759
        }
    ]
}
```

For example in case 1 would be: genreID = 10765, then searching, I found "Action & Adventure". Done, and finish that search.
Go for the second one, the 10474 is not there, the 18 is there, so it is "Animation".

I already have the corresponding struct to have the model of each one.

I thing it would be using `forEach` or something of that, but I'm very new in swift at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a dictionary from your genres model array for faster lookup. Considering you have a Genre struct like this.

```
struct Genre {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Generate a genre dictionary look-up using [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(grouping:by:)) and [`reduce(_:_)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/reduce(_:_:)) like this.

```
let genres = [Genre(id: 10765, name: "Action & Adventure"), Genre(id: 18, name: "Animation")]
let genresLookup = Dictionary(grouping: genres, by: \.id).reduce([Int: String](), { (result, arg) in
    var result = result
    result[arg.key] = arg.value.first?.name
    return result
})
```

**OR**

You can also generate a genre dictionary look-up using [`Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(_:uniquingkeyswith:)) as @TylerP suggested.

```
let genresLookup = Dictionary(genres.map { ($0.id, $0.name) }, uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
```

The type of `genresLookup` is `[Int: String]`, so now you just need to pass the `id` to this dictionary to get the genre name.

```
print(genresLookup[10765] ?? "") // Action & Adventure
```

With this, you don't need to filter your genre array each time to get the name of a genre.

```
for id in genre_ids {
    print(genresLookup[id] ?? "")
}
```

Comment: @TylerP Yes, totally missed that one, thanks for correcting this and typo mistakes, edited my answer